# Can't find Flask template specified by relative path

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to render the `index.html` template in my Flask app's templates folder. However, I get a `TemplateNotFound` error. The template exists. How do I render it?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('../../templates/index.html')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "G:\Projects\Intellij\Python\HelloPython\controller\web\WebHomeController.py", line 10, in webIndex
    return render_template('../../templates/index.html', message=message)
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 133, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 57, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "G:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 85, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: ../../templates/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

[`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.render_template) takes the name to be looked up by the Jinja env, which has the `templates` folder it its lookup path. Only specify the path *after* that.

```
# index.html is in the templates folder
render_template('index.html')

# users/detail.html is in a sub-folder under templates
render_template('users/detail.html')
```